# How to use "-A" in "use dbname;"

Tags: mysql, database, mysql5

When running `use dbname;` in MySQL admin, I will get this message:

```
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
```

But I still not clear about how to use `-A`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-A` (or equivalently `--no-auto-rehash`) is to be added as an option to `mysql` when starting it from a command line, e.g.:

```
mysql -p -u myusername -A
```

Are you running `mysql` from a shell prompt, or through some web admin interface?